# Why is Grand Cayman not a valid location in SO Careers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

There are programming positions in Grand Cayman and there are programming jobs in the Caribbean Islands.  Neither of these is allowed in the "Relocation" choices under Careers.

You guys don't like sunny climates or what?

Comment: It is just because every job offering in the Caribbeans are automatically 'awarded' to one of the SE team. They *do* like sunny islands. A lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to determine whether a location is valid we assign a particular search term a quality.

Our logic is essentially:

```
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types
if (googlePlace.HasComponent("street_address") || googlePlace.HasComponent("route"))
{
    return 87;
}

if (googlePlace.HasComponent("city") || googlePlace.HasComponent("locality"))
{
    return 45;
}

if (googlePlace.HasComponent("administrative_area_level_1"))
{
    return 20;
}

if (googlePlace.HasComponent("country"))
{
    return 10;
}

return 0;
```

To be used on the profile screen as somewhere you want to relocate to you need to meet a quality of 10 or above.

However, [Grand Cayman](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&&address=grand%20cayman) is categorised by Google as a 'Natural Feature' or 'Establishment' which maps to a quality level of 0 on our side. Establishment essentially means uncategorised by Google. I've submitted a general item of feedback to them to categorize each island correctly. I guess we'll see what they say.

Google categorises [Cayman Islands](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&&address=cayman%20islands) as a country which maps to a 10 on our side so you could use that in the meantime. I know this isn't the exact location you want to relocate to but I don't think it makes sense to assign natural features or establishments quality values.

[Carribbean Islands](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&&address=Caribbean%20Islands) on the other hand is marked as a political region because it isn't any single country but a group of countries governed by different governments. We don't currently support this or whole continents in the profile pages. I'll discuss with the team and update this post to see whether it makes sense to treat these as countries!

Comment: Cayman Islands is indeed a country so that is right.  Grand Cayman is like a city within a country, even though there are city like entities on that island.  I'm not sure how you could pull this off, but if I put in the wrong thing, could you suggest the right thing?  Picking up on Cayman and suggesting Cayman Islands from Grand Cayman.

Comment: @Mark0978 heh, define the 'wrong thing'. We know that the quality of a result isn't good enough but we don't have enough information to hint at what we thought you meant...

Comment: So, [tag:status-not-our-fault]? :)

Comment: @DeanWard  "Wrong thing" is a value that is not a valid location for the field.  I can't know to try Cayman Islands, and I don't get any auto complete as I type to give me clues.  Better stated:  In the error case, use what I typed to make suggestions for me to choose from.  Much like tags popup in a div that let me select the right spelling/hyphenation.

Comment: @Mark0978 would you mind posting that as a feature request. It'll get lost in the comments otherwise. Thanks!