# Suggest valid location names when location score is too low

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Coming from [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250414/why-is-grand-cayman-not-a-valid-location-in-so-careers/250551?noredirect=1#comment818026_250551) is a recommendation to make the Careers site better.

The algorithm for location scores things based on the geocoding service from google.  If the named position returns scores that are too low, show a list of related positions.

> I can't know to try Cayman Islands, and I don't get any auto complete as I type to give me clues. Better stated: In the error case, use what I typed to make suggestions for me to choose from. Much like tags popup in a div that let me select the right spelling/hyphenation.

Comment: I have read your previous question, so I know where this is about, but your post on itself is a bit unclear.